# Questions about Levi Convergence Theorem in Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

I am thinking of some questions about Levi convergence theorem I just learned these days during a real analysis course.

The Levi convergence theorem in real analysis said:

If $E$ is a measurable set, $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is non-negative measurable function sequence on $E$, $f_1 \le f_2 \le \cdots \le f_n \le \cdots$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n = f$

we have 
$$ 
\int_E \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(x) \mathrm{d}x = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_E f_n(x) \mathrm{d}x 
$$

1. It does not pose Lebesgue-integrability constraint on $f_n$ or $f$. Does it hold if $f$ is not Lebesgue integrable ($\int_E f(x) \mathrm{d}x = +\infty$)?
2. Does it hold if we drop the non-negative constraint? I searched some materials and found some counter-examples. But all of them are constructed by non-Lebesgue-integrable $\{f_n\}$ or $f$. So I wonder if $f$ and $\{f_n\}$ are Lebesgue-integrable, can we drop the non-negative condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)  Yes.  If $f \ge 0$ is not Lebesgue integrable, then for any positive integer $N$ there is $g$ such that $0 \le g \le f$, $g$ is Lebesgue integrable, and
$\int_E g(x)\; dx > N$.  Apply the Lebesgue-integrable case of
the theorem to $g_n = \min(g, f_n)$ and conclude that $\int_E f_n(x)\; dx > N$
for sufficiently large $n$.

2) Yes, you can use the Dominated Convergence Theorem in that case.

Comment: hmmm... excuse me, I understand 1) now. But for 2) if $f$ and $f_n$ are integrable, and we drop the non-negative condition, how can we use dominated convergence theorem? Because $f_n(x)$ can be negative, it may not be controlled by $f(x)$

Comment: It is dominated by $|f_1| + |f|$.

Comment: cool!I got it now